# Throttle JS Event Listeners added by 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, event-handling, underscore.js, throttling

I want to throttle function calls which are added as Event Listeners to the window.scroll function by a 3rd party library provided by an external supplied (cant be changed).

I figured out that the library causes some overhead by its scroll event listener, because if I remove the event handler, my page runs much smoother.

As I cannot directly control or change the external JS file, I thought to read the scroll-events attached to the Window and delete / rebind them again, but in a throttled format, as I have already the Underscore.js library in use.

I'm trying to read the Scroll events and than replace the function callback as a throttled version:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let scrollEvents = $._data(window, 'events').scroll;
    for(evt of scrollEvents ) { 
      evt.handler = _.throttle(evt.handler, 200) 
    }
  });
```

Does not seem to bring the appropriate improvement. In the Webdeveloper Bar "Global Event Listeners" I still see the original event listeners attached, I do NOT see the Underscore Library (as intermediate layer) listed there.

What is potentially wrong with this code?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Those events are added globally to the Window, see WebDev Screenshot:
[image] and I run the above code within the WebDev console, so it is ran only after those events exist already.

AND `$._data(window, 'events').scroll;` shows ALL those 5 events, so jQuery should be able to change them, isnt it?

Comment: Numerous possibilities: events aren't on window or they aren't initialized using jQuery or they are initialized after this code runs just to name a few. What do you see when inspect `scrollEvents `?

Comment: @charlietfl: Already, please check my EDIT, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a beautiful solution using Underscore.js, proxying the callback functions by a Throttler before adding it as Event Handler:

```
    var f_add = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    var f_remove = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener;

    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, fn, capture) {
        this.f = f_add;
        if(type == 'scroll' && typeof _ === 'function') 
            fn = _.throttle(fn, 350);
        this.f(type, fn, capture);
    }

    EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, fn, capture) {
        this.f = f_remove;
        if(type == 'scroll' && typeof _ === 'function')
            fn = _.throttle(fn, 350);
        this.f(type, fn, capture);
    }
```

It overwrites the prototype for add/removeEventListener -> And if the event is a scroll event, it surrounds the Function `fn` with _.throttle().